# Добавление массива с ключом и значением в mysql

Tags: php, mysql, массивы

Пытаюсь добавить в таблицу массив. Пробую так

```
$query="SELECT * FROM letters";
$result=mysqli_query($db,$query) or die("error".mysqli_error($db));
preg_match_all("~[^\s]{1}~u", $replace, $arrayletters);
foreach (array_count_values($arrayletters[0]) as $k => $v){
    $query="INSERT INTO letters (kkey, vvalue) values ('".$k."', '".$v."')";
    $result=mysqli_query($db,$query) or die("error".mysqli_error($db));
}
```

Но не получается

Comment: какая ошибка што именно не выходит

Comment: В таблицу то добавляет. Но записи перезаписываются. То есть такой способ сам по себе не верный

Comment: ну так структуру таблицы покажите в вопросе?

Comment: таблица называется letters. Поле kkey в котором буквы хранятся и vvalue в котором хранится сколько раз эта буква встретилась. Есть еще таблица - site. В ней хранится информация о сайте. Я думаю для связи id сайта присваивать к каждой записи о букве для связи.

Comment: @demamon если не сложно, выполните SHOW CREATE TABLE letters и дополните результатом ответ.

Comment: letters
     CREATE TABLE `letters` (
     `kkey` varchar(11) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
     `vvalue` int(11) NOT NULL,
     `id_zapis` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `id_site` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id_zapis`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=56 DEFAULT        CHARSET=utf8